# Map filtered array to new array with only a subset of attributes

Tags: arrays, filter, ramda.js

How can I map the values of the this filter to a new array. My filter is working fine but my end result needs to have a property from the array im filter on. I"m using ramda.

```
let bugs = bugsfromBugzilla();
let users = utils.ReadJsonFile('./team.json');
      let data = R.filter(bug => {
        return R.any(filter => {
          return R.contains(filter.assignee, bug.assigned_to);
        }, users);
      }, bugs);
```

the users array is like so :

```
[
  {
    "assignee": "jesse@email.com",
    "id": 843568062370470
  },
  {
    "assignee": "Ryan@email.com",
    "id": 848490202942168
  }
]
```

I need id to be a part of the data variable. Also would be nice if i could only map what attributes i want in the new array.

Comment: What happens if multiple assignees match?  That is, if `bug.assigned_to = ['Ryan@email.com', 'jesse@email.com', 'fred@email.com']` ?

Comment: You can choose your attributes with [`R.project`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#project).

Comment: If can only be assigned to one person at a time, R.project is what I'm looking for I believe

Comment: So is `bug.assigned_to` an array always containing a single string?  Or is it a different data structure?

Comment: Its a attribute of the array. A single string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still not entirely clear what's wanted here without sample input or output data.  (OK, we do have the sample users, but no sample bugs.)

#### Using `pipe`

Still, I think this might be close:

```js
const {contains, pipe, filter, any, project, map, assoc, prop, find} = R

const checkMatch = bug => user => contains(user.assignee, bug.assigned_to)

const extract = (users) => pipe(
  filter(bug => any(checkMatch(bug), users)),
  project(['bug_id', 'assigned_to', 'bar']),
  map(bug => assoc('user_id', prop('id', find(checkMatch(bug), users)), bug)),
)

const bugs = [
  {bug_id: 'abc', assigned_to: "jesse@email.com",           foo: 1, bar: 42, baz: 'z'},
  {bug_id: 'def', assigned_to: "fred@flintstone.com",       foo: 2, bar: 43, baz: 'y'},
  {bug_id: 'ghi', assigned_to: "jesse@email.com",           foo: 3, bar: 44, baz: 'x'},
  {bug_id: 'jkl', assigned_to: "Ryan@email.com",            foo: 4, bar: 45, baz: 'w'},
  {bug_id: 'mno', assigned_to: "Mr. Ryan <Ryan@email.com>", foo: 5, bar: 46, baz: 'v'},
  {bug_id: 'pqr', assigned_to: "wilma@flintstone.com",      foo: 6, bar: 47, baz: 'u'}
]
const users = [
  {"assignee": "jesse@email.com", "id": 843568062370470},
  {"assignee": "Ryan@email.com", "id": 848490202942168}
]

console.log(extract(users)(bugs))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Note that because of the delay between question/response on the comments, I am making a guess at why you need `contains` here.  I am guessing that you might have a value like `Mr. Ryan <Ryan@email.com>` that needs to match `Ryan@email.com`.  If you have exact matches instead, I would instead write:

```
const checkMatch = bug => user => user.assignee === bug.assigned_to
```

#### Trying `reduce`

Usually I find such solutions, piping together steps, are cleaner than `reduce`-based ones.  But because these steps are all fairly complex, and I had reuse the user found in filtering to update the object, I tried a `reduce` one for comparison.  And I actually prefer it:

```js
const {reduce, find, contains, append, assoc, pick} = R

const extract = (users) => reduce((all, bug) => {
  const user = find( user => contains(user.assignee, bug.assigned_to), users);
  return user
    ? append(assoc('user_id', user.id, pick(['bug_id', 'assigned_to', 'bar'], bug)), all)
    : all
}, [])
                                    
const bugs =[{"assigned_to": "jesse@email.com", "bar": 42, "baz": "z", "bug_id": "abc", "foo": 1}, {"assigned_to": "fred@flintstone.com", "bar": 43, "baz": "y", "bug_id": "def", "foo": 2}, {"assigned_to": "jesse@email.com", "bar": 44, "baz": "x", "bug_id": "ghi", "foo": 3}, {"assigned_to": "Ryan@email.com", "bar": 45, "baz": "w", "bug_id": "jkl", "foo": 4}, {"assigned_to": "Mr. Ryan <Ryan@email.com>", "bar": 46, "baz": "v", "bug_id": "mno", "foo": 5}, {"assigned_to": "wilma@flintstone.com", "bar": 47, "baz": "u", "bug_id": "pqr", "foo": 6}]

const users = [{"assignee": "jesse@email.com", "id": 843568062370470}, {"assignee": "Ryan@email.com", "id": 848490202942168}]

console.log(extract(users)(bugs))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

(Again, I would choose `user.assignee === bug.assigned_to` instead of `contains` if the data supports it.)